# Android File open failed: EROFS

Tags: android, file, exception

Sometimes I get Exception.java.io.FileNotFoundException, file open failed: EROFS ( Read- only file System) . I have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my manifest, once in a while when I have my services running then I get these exceptions and few operations will not be succeeded but if I reboot my device then it works fine. 
I want to catch "Exception.java.io.FileNotFoundException" exception and reboot my device programmatically. My device is rooted one so I programmatically execute "su -c reboot".

I need to know how to catch " File open failed: EROFS " exception and trigger a reboot ??

Comment: that exception doesn't mean that there's no file to open?, anyway what about enclosing the portion of code that will throw the exception? try{your code}catch(FileNotFoundException e){reboot here?} should do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will solve your problem this:

```
    try{
        do whatever
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        if("EROFS ( Read- only file System)".equals(ex.getMessage())){
           call code for reboot 
        }
    }
```

You can replace the error message or even skip it

Edit:  - based on comment

```
    try{
        do whatever
    }catch(IOException ex){
        if((ex instanceof FileNotFoundException) &&  "EROFS ( Read- only file System)".equals(ex.getMessage())){
           call code for reboot 
        }
    }
```

Comment: The above code works for me but I need to catch that exception in many places in my code.. If I want to use " extends FileNotFoundException  class " then how can I catch that exception

Comment: than catch his parent IOException http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html and press upvote, if  Ihave helped , thanks

Comment: Is it this way ???    <pre> import java.io.IOException;

    public class FileNotFoundException extends IOException {

     public FileNotFoundException( ) {
     super();
     If ("EROFS ( Read- only file System)".equalsIgnoreCase( getMessage() ) ) {
   // reboot 
  }
 }

 Override
 public String getMessage() {
  return super.getMessage();
 } 
 
}    </pre>

Comment: @user1810931 no. I  will update my answer, your custom exception will not be thrown by Android API, see updated version ( after Edit)