# Can't read a file for strange reason

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have these methods for reading and writing to a file:

```
/* Write content to a file */
    private void writeToFile(ArrayList<String> list) {
        File file = new File("jokesBody1.bjk");     
        FileOutputStream fos;
        if(list != null){
        try {           
                file.createNewFile();
                fos = openFileOutput("jokesBody1.bjk",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                out.writeObject(list);
                out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        }else{
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                fos = openFileOutput("jokesBody1.bjk",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                out.writeObject("");
                out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        }
    }

    /* Read file's content */
    private ArrayList<String> readFromFile() {
        File file = new File("jokesBody1.bjk");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( new FileInputStream( file ) );
            try {
                list = (ArrayList)ois.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ois.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("log activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Everyrhing seems to be fine to me, but when I run the code I'm getting the following error:

```
02-15 17:02:07.655: E/log activity(1882): Can not read file: java.io.IOException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

**Why** the system is `read only`? Should I do something when I'm creating the file if it does not exist by `file.createNewFile();`?

I know that I'm missing something extremely small, but as a total beginner, I'm not able to spot it.

Comment: You don't need to call createNewFile () when you're about to open a file for output, and you *shouldn't* call it when you're  about to open it for input, otherwise you get an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error probably on Linux.
This file system is mounted as read-only.
So you cannot write to it.

Comment: Check the permissions, the type of the file system on which this file resides, anything in that direction. This is basically what this error means. Could be that the account you're using has no permissions to write to it or something similar.

Comment: I don't know where the emulator is creating the application dirs. :(

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711098/trying-to-create-a-file-in-android-open-failed-erofs-read-only-file-system

Comment: "I don't know where the emulator is creating the application dirs." I guess now is a good time to learn these details :)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418930/android-file-open-failed-erofs

Comment: If you Google search your error you'll find lots of resources.